# How to Display key labels and values in Jekyll for loop data that has been grouped

Tags: loops, for-loop, jekyll

I got the following to work:

```
{% assign cars = site.data.inventory %}
{% for item in cars %}
{{item}}
{% endfor %}
```

The result looks like a jumble of key pairs.

```
{"brand"=>"Toyota", "model"=>"Celica"}
```

etc.

All good.  Then I threw it a curve ball.

```
{% assign cars = site.data.inventory | group_by:"model" %}
```

Now the result looks different, and that makes sense, but it's causing confusion.

```
{"name"=>"Celica","items"=>[{"brand"=>"Toyota", "model"=>"Celica"}], "size"=>1}
```

Where this becomes a challenge:

I want to iterate through the "items" in the **2nd** result, pulling only the key labels.  If I *remove* the grouping, I can do this:

```
{% for e in cars %}
{% if forloop.first == true %}
  {% for item in e %}
    {{item[0]}}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
  {% for item in e %}
    {{item[1]}}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Works like a charm.  The first result is the label, the remaining results show the data.  A simple way to make a column header.

However, if I add the group_by in the assign, my {{item[0]}} becomes "name", "items", "size", instead of "brand", "model" where items becomes the entire list {{item}} from the first example.

How do I iterate through the values in bold?

**[{"brand"=>"Toyota", "model"=>"Celica"}]** while they are grouped?

Comment: Can you add to your question the exact output you are trying to get.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's what you're trying to do :

```
{% assign models = site.data.inventory | group_by:"model" %}

<table>
{% for model in models %}

  {% if forloop.first == true %}
  <tr>
    {% for item in model.items.first %}
      <th>{{ item[0] }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% endif %}

  {% for car in model.items %}
  <tr>
    {% for field in car %}
      <td>{{ field[1] }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
</table>
```